# What are the best practices for determining when (or not) to pre-compile a Linq Query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, compiled-query

I am currently refactoring a silverlight application and pulling out frequently used queries to a utility class.  There are a lot of queries in the application, and while there were some obvious targets, when I get down to very small queries like this:

```
public static readonly Func<STARSEntities, int> CurrentFundingYearId =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<STARSEntities, int>(
        (ctx) =>
            (ctx.STARS_FundingYear.Where(i => i.IsCurrentYear == true)).FirstOrDefault().FundingYearId);
```

Is it worth compiling?  Everything I've read ([Programming Entity Framework 2ed](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596807269)) and various online sources say that there are performance boosts, but I haven't found anything that outlines when NOT to pre-compile (besides the fact that you can't return anonymous types, so no projection).

Edit: Good background article about compiled queries: [Precompiling LINQ Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336024.aspx)

What are the best practices for determining when (or not) to pre-compile a Linq Query in an application?